# gcc shows segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run this very simple program which implements counting sort. The program runs into a segmentation fault.
I have run into similiar questions in here, but they all deal with pointers.
My code has no pointers and when I run the code on gcc 7.3.0 it seems like for loop for scanning integers is looping forever. But when I ran it on gcc 4.8.5 then it shows segmentation fault. I am completely lost here.
My code is:

```
`

void main(){

int i=0,j=0,tmp=0,elements[10],max_ele=0,size_arr[max_ele],sorted_arr[10];

printf("Please enter 5 elements\n");

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%d",&elements[i]);
            }

//Finding max element in the elements array
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(max_ele<elements[i]){
                max_ele=elements[i];
                }
        }

//Setting size_arr as 0
for(i=0;i<max_ele;i++){
        size_arr[i]=0;
}


//Setting the count of elements present
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        size_arr[elements[i]]++;
        }

//Sorting
for(i=0;i<=max_ele;i++){
        tmp=size_arr[i];
        while(tmp--){
                sorted_arr[j]=i;
                j++;
                }
        }
printf("Sorted array is:\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d\n",sorted_arr[i]);
        }

}`
```

Comment: Hint: `size_arr[max_ele]` does not automatically get resized when you change the value of `max_ele`.

Comment: Does this mean that, given I have already set max_ele=0, size_arr have allocated no space at all?

Comment: I removed the declaration of size_arr[] from the top. And then , declared it after the for loop for finding out the max_ele in the array. Now, it is working as intended. Thank you.